# Total newb trying to build a wireless power transfer system for terrarium water pump

Tags: wireless, induction, power-transfer

I am needing to build a induction based wireless power transfer system that I can use to power a small aquarium pump through the glass base of a very tall vase. I have been researching this for about a month now and am about to give up. Let me be straight, I cant do math. I never made it past 8th grade in it. So when all the research I find is very math heavy I go cross-eyed. Would anyone be able to help me design the circuit I need? I am sure I can build it myself I just cant figure out all the parts and how to decided the frequencies needed. The power label on the pump states the needed power is 4-6V DC between 0.6 and 1.8W. I can tell you the distance I need to send the power is between 22mm and 30mm. There is also a limit to the diameter of the receiver coil as well, as the base of the vase is only 14cm wide. Is this a pipe dream because I cant find any good resources that I can understand?

Comment: Have you considered using something like a stir plate and just having the impeller be driven through the glass by a rotating magnet on the other side?  No math there and no electronics in the water.

Comment: That is an idea worth giving thought to. However I am not sure i would be able to achieve the lift height with a setup like that. The thick glass base I think would would inhibit the amount of "torque(?)" I would be able to transmit to the impeller. I need to lift the water about 3 feet straight up. I don't need a huge amount of flow but I cant just have a dribble. I need enough for a waterfall effect. I am going to look into this, It just might work if I can get the torque.